# Migrate entire collection data to another solr instance with same collection

Tags: solr

I have 2 identical solr instances. One is for production and one is for testing. I want to migrate a collection 'NEWS' from *prod* to *test*.

Both prod and test have same collection with same configurations. I just want to copy the data from one to the other

Is there a way to do this in solr?

Answer (score 0):

If the servers have access to a common, shared network location, you can [issue a BACKUP command on your production node](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/collection-management.html#backup), and then [a RESTORE command on your test node](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/collection-management.html#restore):

```bash
curl -X POST http://prodnode:8983/api/collections -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
  {
    "backup-collection": {
      "name": "techproducts_backup",
      "collection": "techproducts",
      "location": "file:///path/to/my/shared/drive"
    }
  }
'

curl -X POST http://testnode:8983/api/collections -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
  {
    "restore-collection": {
      "name": "techproducts_backup",
      "collection": "techproducts_v3",
      "location": "file:///path/to/my/shared/drive"
    }
  }
'
```

If you don't have a network drive, you can create the backup locally and then copy it over to the other node and restore it there. If the configuration is identical as you say I'd prefer to go this route (it'll also test that you're able to make backups and restore them).

Another option is to [use the SolrEntityProcessor in DIH](https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html#solrentityprocessor) - but DIH is not bundled with 9.x, so you'll have to install the community project yourself if you're on 9.x.

```xml
<dataConfig>
  <document>
    <entity name="sep" processor="SolrEntityProcessor"
            url="http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/db "
            query="*:*"
            fl="*,orig_version_l:_version_,ignored_price_c:price_c"/>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

The third option is to use the `/export` endpoint or something similar with a CSV writer, then import the CSV file directly into the other node through the regular `/update` endpoints. CSVs are usually the most effective exchange format if you have a flat index. This will do an actual reindexing of the data, and might not be what you're looking for.